# Calculate R2-predicted in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to use code from [here](https://gist.github.com/benjaminmgross/d71f161d48378d34b6970fa6d7378837) but am running into a couple issues. First, the author explains that `xs` are the independent variables, which I would think is a 1-dimensional array of independent variable values. This causes an issue with the line `hat = xs.dot(np.linalg.pinv(xs))`, which requires a 2-dimensional array. If I try inputting a 2-dimensional array with x and y values I get to the line `sqr = np.square(res/den)` at which point I receive the error `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (40,) (2,)`.

Here is the code I have all together.

```
def press_statistic(y_true, y_pred, xs):
"""
Calculation of the `Press Statistics <https://www.otexts.org/1580>`_
"""
res = y_pred - y_true
hat = xs.dot(np.linalg.pinv(xs))
den = (1 - np.diagonal(hat))
sqr = np.square(res/den)
return sqr.sum()

def func_fit(x,a,b,x0,y0):
return y0+(a/(1+((x/x0)**b)))

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func_fit,x,y,p0=[10,-20,30,1],maxfev=10000)

x = array([ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22,
   23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39,
   40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45], dtype=int64)

y = array([0.95823096, 0.96642097, 0.97461097, 0.98280098, 0.98280098,
   0.98280098, 0.98280098, 0.99099099, 0.999181  , 0.999181  ,
   0.999181  , 1.00737101, 1.00737101, 1.01556102, 1.01556102,
   1.02375102, 1.02375102, 1.03194103, 1.03194103, 1.04013104,
   1.04832105, 1.04832105, 1.04832105, 1.06470106, 1.08927109,
   1.17117117, 1.36773137, 1.71990172, 2.08845209, 2.36691237,
   2.6044226 , 2.80917281, 2.97297297, 3.11220311, 3.25143325,
   3.35790336, 3.45618346, 3.55446355, 3.63636364, 3.7018837 ])

xs = x
y_true = y
y_pred = func_fit(x,*popt)

press = press_statistic(y_true=y_true,y_pred=y_pred,xs=xs)
```

I also want to use the `predicted_r2` function, but so far I'm stuck on PRESS.

EDIT: Please see my attempted answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I've attempted calculating the PRESS statistic based on the formula and my understanding that it is calculated by fitting n models for each ith observation in a data set with i left out. Here is my code for that:

```
press = 0
for i in range(0,len(x)):
    x_drop = np.delete(x,i)
    y_drop = np.delete(y,i)
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(func_fit,x_drop,y_drop,p0=[10,-20,30,1],maxfev=10000)
    y_data = func_fit(x,*popt)
    yi_res = (y[i]-y_data[i])**2
    press = press+yi_res
```

Calculating R2_pred after this should be simple.

```
ss_tot = np.sum((y-np.mean(y))**2)
r2_pred = 1-press/ss_tot
```

If anyone could confirm my calculations here, that would be great! Hopefully I'm at least close now.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a late answer but I still made it. You don't really need to do n times of linear regression, as shown in the book 'Introduction to Linear Regression Analysis' by Montgomery, PRESS statistics can be calculated by predicted residuals e(i) and the diagonal terms of hat matrix. Also, I am not sure if you have a typo in this sentence 'sqr = np.square(res/den)', where square should actually be **2 according to the definition. By calculating the square of residual/denominator you might get a unreasonably high predicted r-squared.

Here are my codes. I have tested it on several models and the metric results are consistent(high MAE/MAPE with a low pred r^2) .

```
def predicted_r2(x_test, y_true, y_pred):

    X = x_test.values

    
    hat = X.dot(np.linalg.pinv(np.transpose(X).dot(X)).dot(np.transpose(X)))
    denom = (1 - np.diag(hat))
    resid = np.abs(y_pred - y_true).to_numpy()
    PRESS = np.sum((resid/denom)**2)

    
    SST = np.sum((y_true - y_true.mean())**2)

    
    pred_r2 = 1 - PRESS/SST
    return(pred_r2)
```